# IBM.XMS MQ Listener Error 2063 or how to create connection without credentials

Tags: c#, listener, ibm-mq, xms

I'm trying to implement an MQ Listener in a windows service and I have used the xms mq consumer sample provided in the dotnet folder from the MQ Explorer installation. I am using MQ WebSphere 7.1

If I run their sample solution in console, everything works.

However, in my windows service it fails with MQ Reason Code: 2063.

I'm using these settings for my factory

```
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, _queueHost);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, Convert.ToInt32(_queuePort));
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, _queueChannel);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, 0);
```

and then this line seems to be failing

```
IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection(null,null);
```

I don't want to provide any user credentials, is that possible?

I've tried changing the CONNECTION_MODE to bindings and getting different errors as well.

Is the sample code only working because I am running it and therefore it is using my local credentials by default? Otherwise I am using the same config in both.

Answer (score 1):

The MQ XMS client is propagating the logged on user to the queue manager, then the QM checks its authority records to determine whether that user can connect and what objects it may access.

You could set the authority records to allow the user currently used to run the service, or you could set the logged on user on the windows service to match an allowed user of the queue manager, or set the MCAUSER property on the server connection channel used to connect to the queue manager, if you use client connection.

Setting the MCAUSER on the server connection channel will allow anyone who can connect to that channel to impersonate the set user, so this should be used with caution, possibly with setting appropriate channel authentication records.

References:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_rtrouble_tips.html

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q010530_.htm

Comment: Thanks for that, I had forgotten to add that this was a local server and that caused all sorts of problems because I had done what you suggested already. Every is working correctly now that I uninstalled it and followed instructions from here -> http://www.jamestheintegrationguy.com/setting-up-a-development-websphere-mq-server/